# Array values with Word for e.g. Two - 2, Three - 3

Tags: php, arrays, function, numbers

Here's array i m using

```
$a = array("1"=>2,"2"=>8,"3"=>9,"4"=>8,"5"=>6,"6"=>7,"7"=>9,"8"=>2);
```

And i am trying to get output something like this
when 2 print Two-2, when 3 print Three-3

```
//Desired Output
Two - 2
Eight -8
Nine - 9
```

I got this desired output by using another array

And this code which creates array of arrays using null as callback in array_map() function

```
$b = array("Two", "Eight", "Nine", "Eight", "Six", "Seven", "Nine", "Two");

$array = array_map(null, $a, $b);
    
    foreach($array as $value) {
        
        echo $value[1]."-".$value[0]."<br>";
}
```

So , **what i want to do is get a desired OUTPUT without using this another array $b**. I am having no idea about how to do without using another array.
is it possible to do with any condition or am i asking silly question? I just started learning php.

I tried finding solution but i didn't reached there. if there is already a solution about this please Refer me

Comment: Can't u just change the key or the value of array $a?

Comment: Use `array_combine($b, $a)` instead of `array_map` than you can `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// $a = array("1"=>2,"2"=>8,"3"=>9,"4"=>8,"5"=>6,"6"=>7,"7"=>9,"8"=>2); // used short array notation (see references) and removed keys (since not used)
$numbers = [2,8,9,8,6,7,9,2,95890814984141]; // the last number is for my pleasure :P
$numberFormatter = new NumberFormatter('en', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $numberSpelled = $numberFormatter->format($number);
    $numberSpelledWithFirstCharUpper = ucfirst($numberSpelled);
    
    echo $numberSpelledWithFirstCharUpper . ' - ' . $number . PHP_EOL;
}
```

### output

```
Two - 2
Eight - 8
Nine - 9
Eight - 8
Six - 6
Seven - 7
Nine - 9
Two - 2
Ninety-five trillion eight hundred ninety billion eight hundred fourteen million nine hundred eighty-four thousand one hundred forty-one - 95890814984141
```

Working [example](https://3v4l.org/1mcaS).

### references

- [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)
- [Short array notation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-57)
- [ucfirst](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)
- [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

---

### Pro-Tip

Give your variables [meaningful names](https://medium.com/coding-skills/clean-code-101-meaningful-names-and-functions-bf450456d90c) - makes the code much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to create another array or put the value on existing array for this But it's will well practice if you not use `array_map()` for this.

```
foreach($a as $key=>$value) {
    
    echo $b[$key]."-".$value."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a lookup array and:

```
$lookup = [
    'zero',
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    'four',
    // etc...
];
$a = array("1"=>2,"2"=>4,"3"=>1,"4"=>1,"5"=>2,"6"=>3,"7"=>3,"8"=>2);
foreach ($a as $num) {
    echo $lookup[$num] . '-' . $num;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/WGr9V).